# How to center a text in mui snackbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, snackbar

I'm trying to center a text in a muisnackbar but unfortunately I can't do it.
Here is the code

I am taker of any proposal

```
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Snackbar from "@mui/material/Snackbar";
import MuiAlert, { AlertProps } from "@mui/material/Alert";

const Alert = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, AlertProps>(function Alert(
  props,
  ref
) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} ref={ref} variant="filled" {...props} />;
});

export default function CustomizedSnackbars() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = (
    event?: React.SyntheticEvent | Event,
    reason?: string
  ) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Stack spacing={2} sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open success snackbar
      </Button>
      <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
        <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success" sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
          This is a success message!
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

I tested justifyContent, AlignItem , AlignContent but in vain
Thank you in advance

Comment: Why using Alert inside Snackbar? Shouldn't it be either Snackbar for small and snack at sides or bottom for less important message. Or Alert in Front of everything for very important message? Maybe Alert prevent it to align the way it is designed. And you could try to use Typography instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass this prop to a Snackbar component

```
ContentProps={{
  sx: {
    display: 'block',
    textAlign: "center"
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

To center a text inside Snackbar you can use [`.MuiAlert-message`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/alert/#css) class, styles of this class will be applied to the message wrapper element. Like:-

```js
<Snackbar open={true} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
    <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success" sx={{ width: '300px','& .MuiAlert-message':{textAlign:"center", width:"inherit"} }}>
       This is a success message!
    </Alert>
</Snackbar>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,  Actually the text inside is centered bu even the icon lust be centered I tried to do that but it doesn't work